# Real-Time Messaging with Web Sockets in Django Rest Framework and ReactJS - How to Save Messages to Database?

Tags: python, reactjs, database, rest, django-rest-framework

I am developing a chat application using Django Rest Framework (DRF) and ReactJS, aiming to implement real-time sending and receiving of messages through Web Sockets. While exploring resources on YouTube and blogs, I found most tutorials lacking information on saving these real-time messages to the database.

Here's a snippet of my relevant `views.py` and `models.py` code:

**views.py:**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView, ListCreateAPIView
from .models import GroupChat, Messages
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
import uuid, re
```

**models.py:**

```py
class CreateGroup(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = GroupChat
    serializer_class = GroupChatSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                serializer.data, status =  status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        return Response(
            serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
    

class SendMessage(ListCreateAPIView):
    lookup_field = "group_id"
    queryset = Messages
    serializer_class = MessagesSerializer

    def post(self, request,group_id, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if GroupChat.objects.filter(group_id = group_id).exists() == False:
            return Response({
                "details": "group chat not found"
            }, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        request.data["group"] = group_id
        
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                serializer.data, status =  status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        return Response(
            serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
    
    def get(self, request, group_id,  *args, **kwargs):

        if GroupChat.objects.filter(group_id = group_id).exists() == False:
            return Response({
                "details": "group chat not found"
            }, status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        group = GroupChat.objects.get(group_id = group_id)
        messages = Messages.objects.filter(group = group.pk)
        
        serializer = self.serializer_class(messages, many =  True)
        return Response(
            serializer.data
        )


And this is my models.py

from django.db import models
from datetime import timezone
import uuid, re
# Create your models here.


class GroupChat(models.Model):
    group_id = models.CharField(max_length = 100, primary_key=True, unique=True, editable = False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.group_id:
            group_id = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]", self.name)
            group_id = "".join(group_id)
            self.group_id = group_id + str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-", "")[:6]
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Messages(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupChat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "room")
    message = models.CharField(max_length=9999)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.group)
```

I'm seeking guidance on the following:

1. How can I adapt my existing Django views and models to handle real-time messages and persist them in the database?
2. Are there specific modifications or additional components required in both Django and ReactJS to achieve this functionality?

I would greatly appreciate any advice, code snippets, or recommended resources related to integrating real-time messaging with database storage. Thank you for your help!